# How to import nested XML into R data frame

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, tidyverse, xml2

I am looking to import the following XML document into data frames:
http://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/data/donuts.xml

There should be 3 data frames created:

1. Items - (Fields = ID Type    Name    PPU)
2. Batters - (Fields = BatterID, BatterName, ItemID - key to Items data frame)
3. Toppings - (Fields = ToppingID, ToppingName, ItemID - key to Items data frame)

(Data does not need to be 3NF - i.e. each batter can be repeated for each item it is listed against)

Using the XML2 package, I have so far used the following code to import the XML and convert it to a nested list:

```
library(xml2)
xmlobj <- read_xml("http://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/data/donuts.xml")
ls1 <- as_list(xmlobj) #Converts XML to a nested list
```

I am now looking to parse / flatten the list into the 3 data frames as described above.

How best to achieve this?  Is it through a series of loops (lapply/map), passing objects into vectors an then loading the data frame?  Or should I avoid using XML2 / Lists altogether and use the XML package and achieve this using an XPath type syntax?

I tried the following and could pull out the Item attributes and elements for a single item, but when I tried to lapply the function it crashed:

```
#Function for pulling out item attributes from list
ItemDF <- function(myItem){

  #Gather Item data into DF including attributes
  itemFrame <- data_frame(
                id = attr(myItem$item,'id'),
                type = attr(myItem$item,'type'),
                name = unlist(myItem$item$name),
                ppu = unlist(myItem$item$ppu)
              )

  return(itemFrame)
}

#Single instance
df1 <- ItemDF(ls1$items[1])
df1

#Lapply across all items throws an error
lapply(ls1$items,ItemDF)
```

(NB This data set is a proof of concept, so I am looking for a method I can then adapt for other XML files that I expect to be working on).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.

Comment: Added a snippet of what I have tried so far into original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(xml2)
library( tidyverse )

xmlobj <- read_xml("http://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/data/donuts.xml")

df_items <- data.frame( 
  id   = xml_find_all( xmlobj, ".//item" ) %>% xml_attr( "id" ),
  type = xml_find_all( xmlobj, ".//item" ) %>%  xml_attr( "type" ),
  name = xml_find_all( xmlobj, ".//item/name" ) %>% xml_text(),
  ppu  = xml_find_all( xmlobj, ".//item/ppu" ) %>% xml_text(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

#     id   type       name  ppu
# 1 0001  donut       Cake 0.55
# 2 0002  donut     Raised 0.55
# 3 0003  donut Buttermilk 0.55
# 4 0004    bar        Bar 0.75
# 5 0005  twist      Twist 0.65
# 6 0006 filled     Filled 0.75

df_batters <- xml_find_all( xmlobj, ".//item" )  %>% 
  map_df(~{
    set_names(
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//batters/batter") %>% xml_attr( "id" ),
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//batters/batter") %>% xml_text()
    ) %>% 
      as.list() %>%  
      flatten_df() %>%
      mutate(itemID = xml_attr(.x, "id" ) )
  }) %>%
  type_convert() %>% 
  gather( batter, batterID, -itemID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select( batterID, batter, itemID )

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    batterID batter       itemID
#  *    <int> <chr>        <chr> 
#  1     1001 Regular      0001  
#  2     1001 Regular      0002  
#  3     1001 Regular      0003  
#  4     1001 Regular      0004  
#  5     1001 Regular      0005  
#  6     1001 Regular      0006  
#  7     1002 Chocolate    0001  
#  8     1002 Chocolate    0003  
#  9     1003 Blueberry    0001  
# 10     1003 Devil's Food 0001  

df_toppings <- xml_find_all( xmlobj, ".//item" )  %>% 
  map_df(~{
    set_names(
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//topping") %>% xml_attr( "id" ),
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//topping") %>% xml_text()
    ) %>% 
      as.list() %>%  
      flatten_df() %>%
      mutate(itemID = xml_attr(.x, "id" ) )
  }) %>%
  type_convert() %>% 
  gather( topping, toppingID, -itemID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select( toppingID, topping, itemID )

# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#    toppingID topping                  itemID
# *      <int> <chr>                    <chr> 
#  1      5001 None                     0001  
#  2      5001 None                     0002  
#  3      5002 Glazed                   0001  
#  4      5002 Glazed                   0002  
#  5      5002 Glazed                   0005  
#  6      5002 Glazed                   0006  
#  7      5005 Sugar                    0001  
#  8      5005 Sugar                    0002  
#  9      5005 Sugar                    0005  
# 10      5007 Powdered Sugar           0001  
# 11      5007 Powdered Sugar           0006  
# 12      5006 Chocolate with Sprinkles 0001  
# 13      5003 Chocolate                0001  
# 14      5003 Chocolate                0002  
# 15      5003 Chocolate                0004  
# 16      5003 Chocolate                0006  
# 17      5004 Maple                    0001  
# 18      5004 Maple                    0002  
# 19      5004 Maple                    0004  
# 20      5004 Maple                    0006
```

Comment: That's great Wimpel - works very well and I can adapt to other structures quite easily.

Out of interest, were you able to produce a result using the nested list that comes out of the as_list function?  I would be interested to hear your thoughts on whether that would be a good approach or not and how to go about it.

My assumption is that the function is available to allow people to convert XML to lists in this way as some people are more conversant with list parsing than using the XML specific functions.

Comment: @BrisbanePom not sure.. I scraped the above together about half a year ago, using google and SO-answers. So it's a bit rusty...

Comment: @BrisbanePom While the `as_list` "works" it's generally better form to use XPath to target what you need from the XML like @Wimpel did as it tends to be more explicit to the reader (i.e. really shows what's happening) and avoids having to work with cumbersome list slicing constructs.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on that hrbrmstr. I agree that it is easier to interpret, but am still curious as to why the as_list function has been made available - i.e. does it tie in with a more common (tidyverse) approach for handling nested lists and was thus made available for people who preferred handling the data in that way?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents for the key to items data part (batters only):

```
df_batters <- xml_find_all(xmlobj, ".//item") %>% 
  map_df(~{
    bind_cols(
      itemID = xml_attr(.x, "id"),
      batterID = xml_find_all(.x, ".//batters/batter") %>% xml_attr("id"),
      batter = xml_find_all(.x, ".//batters/batter") %>% xml_text()
    )}) %>% type_convert()

#   itemID batterID batter      
#    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>       
#  1 0001       1001 Regular     
#  2 0001       1002 Chocolate   
#  3 0001       1003 Blueberry   
#  4 0001       1003 Devil's Food
#  5 0002       1001 Regular     
#  6 0003       1001 Regular     
#  7 0003       1002 Chocolate   
#  8 0004       1001 Regular     
#  9 0005       1001 Regular     
# 10 0006       1001 Regular
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters my problem. The example above works just fine. But, the xml file I had to deal with for work did not yield anything when using the code above. I had to first introduce the root node at the beginning of the pipeline to get it to work, i.e.:

```
xmlobj %>%
  xml_root() %>%
  xml_find_all(".//item") %>%
  map(.......) %>% .....
```